# UPDATE statement not working in stored procedure; the error is ORU-10027: buffer overflow, limit of 20000 bytes

Tags: oracle, plsql

i'm using oracle sql developer and the code was working perfectly fine but suddenly now it's not working .. when i run the execute line it gives "ORU-10027: buffer overflow, limit of 20000 bytes" error. here is my code

```
create or replace procedure update_painting_price
is
   CURSOR c_painting is  SELECT painting_id, painting_price FROM painting;
   c_paintingid painting.painting_id%type;   
   c_paintingprice painting.painting_price%type;
   total_rows number(2);
BEGIN  
   OPEN c_painting;  
   LOOP  
      FETCH c_painting into c_paintingid, c_paintingprice;  
      UPDATE  painting  
   SET painting_price = painting_price + 50;  
   IF sql%notfound THEN  
      dbms_output.put_line('no painting updated');  
   ELSIF sql%found THEN  
      total_rows := sql%rowcount;  
      dbms_output.put_line( total_rows || ' paintings price updated ');  
   END IF;  
   END LOOP;  
   CLOSE c_painting;  
END;  

 execute  update_painting_price
```

Comment: You have no condition ending your loop until you hit some error / exception

Comment: The procedure adds 50 to the price of every painting, for every loop iteration. Should the update have some `where` condition? What is it meant to do?

Comment: even when i add `where` condition i still got the same error @GaryMyers

Comment: there is no `where` condition. Each price in the table is supposed to increase by 50. @WilliamRobertson

Comment: @maramSt but it updates *every* row, *every* time. If that is really the requirement then you might as well just count the rows and then increase the price of all paintings by 50 * the count. (I don't think that can be the requirement.) Also the loop never ends, which is why you max out the output buffer.

Answer (score 1):

To me, it seems that it'll *suddenly* start working - just like it *suddenly* stopped - only if you **remove** `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` call out of the loop because you exceeded the buffer size.

Have a look at the following example based on Scott's sample schema. It uses a cross (self) join:

```
SQL> begin
  2    dbms_output.enable(2000);
  3    for cur_r in (select a.ename
  4                  from emp a cross join emp b
  5                  )
  6    loop
  7      dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.ename);
  8    end loop;
  9  end;
 10  /
SMITH
SMITH
SMITH
SMITH
<snip>
MILLER
MILLER
MILLER

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

But, if I add yet another `emp` table, buffer limit (2000 bytes) will be exceeded:

```
SQL> begin
  2    dbms_output.enable(2000);
  3    for cur_r in (select a.ename
  4                  from emp a cross join emp b cross join emp c
  5                  )                           ----------------
  6    loop                                      -- newly added
  7      dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.ename);
  8    end loop;
  9  end;
 10  /
SMITH
SMITH
SMITH
<snip>
WARD
WARD
begin
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: ORU-10027: buffer overflow, limit of 2000 bytes
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT", line 32
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT", line 97
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT", line 112
ORA-06512: at line 7


SQL>
```

See? My buffer is set *low* (to only 2000 bytes) while yours is higher, but not high enough. Would it help if you raised it? Probably, but it won't help in what I'm going to write next.

---

Your code seems to be **wrong**. You're looping through the whole `painting` table (which is OK), but `update` updates **all rows** in every loop iteration, so `total_rows` is always equal to number of rows in the table and the same message is displayed all over again. Consider something like this instead:

```
create or replace procedure update_painting_price is
  l_total number := 0;
begin
  for cur_r in (select painting_id, painting_price
                from painting
               )
 loop
   update painting set
     painting_price = painting_price + 50
     where painting_id = cur_r.painting_id;
   l_total := l_total + sql%rowcount;
  end loop;
  
  dbms_output.put_line('Updated ' || l_total || ' row(s)');
end;
/
```

Though, for what you're doing, all you need is a simple SQL statement:

```
update painting set
  painting_price = painting_price + 50;
```

Result will be just the same as that PL/SQL procedure's.